# Ng-Change not getting called on select, option updated

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am having two dropdown d1 and d2.

Here is d1:

```
<select ng-change="getFeeList()">
 <option value="1"> Std 10</option>
  <option value="2"> Std 12</option>
 </select>

 function getFeeList(){
    //Get fee list and update options of d2
 }
```

Here is d2:

```
<select ng-change="getAmount()">
 <option value="F1"> Tutitio Fee</option>
  <option value="F2"> Mess Fee</option>
 </select>
```

On change of d1, options of d2 getting updated(with new values).

Issue is when options of d2 updated on call of `getFeeList()` , `getAmount()` is not getting called however when I am selecting d2 value and changing then `getAmount()` is getting called.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @miraj added code.

Comment: @rmalviya this is working. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, your posted code is not complete but it seems like you want `change` event to trigger after updating the options of `d2` select.
You can manually trigger the change event of select `d2` after updating the options as follows.

Use jQuery [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters):

```
$('#id_of_d2').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

The ng-change directive is not working because it needs an ng-model inside the same element. [See the docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

It should look like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOptionValue" ng-change="getFeeList()">
 <option value="1"> Std 10</option>
 <option value="2"> Std 12</option>
</select>
```

Note that every time you select an option the variable "selectedOptionValue" in your scope is set to the option`s value attribute and after this the code inside ng-change is evaluated.